# Does it make sense to say: "I am trying to"?

Tags: ellipsis

Last week, my friends and I went fishing. I heard two people talking beside us while fishing. I don't know them and will name them A and B. This is what they said.

> A: How long have you been fishing today?
>
> B: two hours
>
> A: Have you caught any fish?
>
> B: No, but I am trying **to**.

B finished his sentence with "to". Don't you need a verb after "to". Is it grammatically correct not to add a verb after it? Please explain it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it makes sense and is grammatically correct. It's essentially short for:

> No, but I am trying to catch some fish

In general:

> **Question**: Have you [done action/activity A]?
>
> **Answer**: No, but I'm trying to [do action/activity A].